# How to send a file to an API that accepts audio files?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an application I prepared with React Native. In this application, I will make an API request and I need to send an audio file in this request. The audio file is available in the location I provided below. How can I send the audio file in this location with the `file` variable of the API?

```js
export const getCompletion5 = async (key) => {

    const configuration = new Configuration({ apiKey: key });
    const openai = new OpenAI(configuration);

    // sound file path
    const filePath = "file:///data/user/0/com.asd.xyz/cache/sound.mp4";

    // how should I prepare this??
    let audioFile;

    try {
        openai.audio.transcriptions.create({
            file: audioFile,
            model: "whisper-1",
        }).then(transcription => {
            console.log(transcription.text);
            return transcription.text
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error("error 1:", error);
        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.error("error 2:", error);
    }

}
```

Comment: You should read the specs of the API. It should describe how you have to send the file.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand exactly what I should do from the spec. https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/audio/createTranscription#file

Comment: There is a cURL example. It uses `-F` to send the file. That is `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: So what should I do? Could you please explain what I should do by writing a normal answer? @jabaa

Comment: No, I won't write the code for you. Read about `multipart/form-data` and try it.

Comment: I tried everything like RNFS and formData creation. Most of the time the saturation code returned 400. If I could I wouldn't even ask the question @jabaa

Comment: This seems to be the file object you get from an input element.